# Is $[A,[A,B]]=0$ generally true in the ring theory of operator?

Tags: commutative-algebra, operator-theory

The identity $[A,[A,B]]=0$ is necessary for identities such as $[\hat{A},\hat{B}^{n}]=n\hat{B}^{n-1}[\hat{A},\hat{B}]$ and hence other identities involving the commutator of an exponentiated operator. By calculation
$$
[A,[A,B]]=AAB+BAA-2ABA
$$
I don't see any reason why this would necessarily be zero. Any ideas?

Comment: To answer the title: No. Related: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula

Comment: Have you tried to find $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ and $[A,B]$ do not commute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find $2\times 2$-matrices $A,B\in M_2(K)$ with $[A,B]=AB-BA=B$, either by a direct computation, or by the adjoint matrices of the nonabelian Lie algebra $\mathfrak{r}_2(K)$ of dimension $2$ over $K$. But then of course
$$
[A,[A,B]]=[A,B]=B.
$$
So for example, take
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},\quad 
B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \cr -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then also $[A,[A,[A,\cdots ,B]]]\cdots ]=B$. In other words, the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{r}_2(K)$ is not nilpotent.

Comment: "Or by the adjoint matrices of the nonabelian Lie algebra" - Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are the adjoint matrices of the Lie algebra with basis $(x,y)$ and Lie brackets $[x,y]=y$. Here $ad(x)(y)=[x,y]$.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ two matrices?

Comment: @Filippo No, $x$ and $y$ are two elements of an abstract Lie algebra (so a vector space). So $x$ and $y$ may be smooth functions in $C^{\infty}$, for example. By Ado's theorem, you may view a finite-dimensional Lie algebra as a matrix algebra, though.

Comment: sorry, I was lost in my thoughts and completely forgot to accept the answer, thanks for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome. If it was helpful for you,  very good.